# ag-grid angular access selectionController.getLastSelectedNode()

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to retrieve the last selected node from gridApi.
I managed to find a private member variable within gridApi, `selectionController`

This controller has a function named getLastSelectedNode().
`selectionController.getLastSelectedNode()`.

Here is the respective source code from ag-grid libary
[selectionController.ts](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/selectionController.ts)

I can do some hacky code, in order to access the private member from `gridApi` like such:
`this.gridApi['selectionController'].lastSelectedNode.data`

However, I am not happy with that approach.
Does anyone know if it is possible to Inject the controller into my service as it has been done within the ag-grid library?
I am interested in adding some code like such in my service:

`@Autowired('selectionController') private selectionController: SelectionController;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
lastSelectedNodes;
[...]
this.gridOptions = {
  onSelectionChanged: (event: SelectionChangedEvent) => {
    if (this.lastSelectedNodes) {
      const lastAdded = event.api.getSelectedNodes().filter(x => !this.lastSelectedNodes.includes(x));
      console.log("last selected node: ", lastAdded);
    }
    this.lastSelectedNodes = event.api.getSelectedNodes();
  }
}
```

Comment: I needed something as easy as `gridApi.lastSelectedNode.data` 

I have the code above. In my question I have mentioned that gridApi has the data for private usage only.It would be nice to have access publicly.